# Trying to run docker container, getting error "api_db_1 exited with code 255"

Tags: docker, db2, docker-compose, containers

I am trying to run docker container but having this issue. Can anybody help me?

```
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
Attaching to api_db_1
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker events <- (filters={'label': ['com.docker.compose.project=api', 'com.docker.compose.oneoff=False
']}, decode=True)
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: https://192.168.99.100:2376 "GET /v1.25/events?filters=%7B%22label%22%3A+%5B%22com.docker.compose.project%3
Dapi%22%2C+%22com.docker.compose.oneoff%3DFalse%22%5D%7D HTTP/1.1" 200 None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker events -> <generator object APIClient._stream_helper at 0x0000000003955E08>
db_1                 | New password: BAD PASSWORD: The password fails the dictionary check - it is based on a dictionary word
db_1                 | Retype new password: Changing password for user db2inst1.
db_1                 | passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.
db_1                 | Setting password for DB2INST1 as: password
db_1                 | SQL1063N  DB2START processing was successful.
db_1                 |
db_1                 |   Creating database "SAMPLE"...
db_1                 |   Existing "SAMPLE" database found...
db_1                 |     The "-force" option was not specified...
db_1                 |   Attempt to create the database "SAMPLE" failed.
db_1                 |   SQL1005N  The database alias "SAMPLE" already exists in either the local
db_1                 | database directory or system database directory.
db_1                 |
db_1                 |
db_1                 |   'db2sampl' processing complete.
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker wait <- ('ef1ac83ba9ef351e2cb2144789071c53d5ea865804f048d3bf3e0030cfe5a848')
urllib3.connectionpool._new_conn: Starting new HTTPS connection (3): 192.168.99.100db_1                 |

compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container <- ('ef1ac83ba9ef351e2cb2144789071c53d5ea865804f048d3bf3e0030cfe5a848')
urllib3.connectionpool._new_conn: Starting new HTTPS connection (4): 192.168.99.100
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: https://192.168.99.100:2376 "POST /v1.25/containers/ef1ac83ba9ef351e2cb2144789071c53d5ea865804f048d3bf3e003
0cfe5a848/wait HTTP/1.1" 200 32
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: https://192.168.99.100:2376 "GET /v1.25/containers/ef1ac83ba9ef351e2cb2144789071c53d5ea865804f048d3bf3e0030
cfe5a848/json HTTP/1.1" 200 None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker wait -> {'Error': None, 'StatusCode': 255}
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container -> {'AppArmorProfile': '',
 'Args': ['start-0.3'],
 'Config': {'ArgsEscaped': True,
            'AttachStderr': False,
            'AttachStdin': False,
            'AttachStdout': False,
            'Cmd': ['start-0.3'],
            'Domainname': '',
            'Entrypoint': ['/entrypoint.sh'],
            'Env': ['PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'],
...
api_db_1 exited with code 255
```

Comment: Hi, please adjust your question to [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), in particular please provide docker-compose file, because there is a problem inside it probably. Another thing is the error trace, please copy and paste it here as a code snippet instead of a link to a photo because this link will expire with time - rather sooner than later.

Answer (score 0):

The action is failing because the sample database already exists in the Db2-instance.

Your options include

- Using the `db2sampl -force` option which will drop and recreate any
  existing sample database
- Don't run `db2sampl` after creating the Db2-instance (i.e. arrange
  for an empty Db2-instance).
- Conditionally drop the sample database (i.e drop if it exists )
  before running your action.